# Find the sum of a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

It's easy to check that the sum 
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sin{\frac{1}{2^n}}
$$
is convergent. Can this sum be calculate precisely?

Comment: Functional analysis????


Comment: I took the liberty of retaging it as series.

Comment: Do you want to express the sum of that series in terms of which known kind of functions/operations/constructions?

Comment: Calculated precisely means what? Is one allowed to use other mathematical constants; and if so, then what is gained?

Comment: Without special functions, I am afraid we can not give a direct result  on this problem

Answer (score 9):

You can rewrite the series as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}{1\over (2^{2n-1}-1)(2n-1)!}.$$
To do this, simply expand each term using the sine series and exchange summations. It is not a closed form, but it converges much more rapidly than the original series.

Comment: Alternatively, one could succesively compute values of 1/2^m  + sum(j=1 to m) sin (1/2^j) until one got tired/satisfied with the amount of effort done.  Gerhard "Some Do This For Fun?" Paseman, 2011.04.01  

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this problem by considering a more general question. Denote function
$$
\zeta(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sin{x^n}, ~ 0 \leq x < 1.
$$
It's obvious that $\zeta(0) = 0$. One can use this this sum to get various differential equations $\zeta$ satisfied. Then once $\zeta$ can be solved explicitly, the above sum is a especial case $x = \frac{1}{2}$. But I have not find a solution yet. Is this approach possible?